# Using the same header files as those in static library

Tags: c++

If a header file (.h) included in the source file has also been included in a static library (.lib), what will happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical library implementation will include its own header, so this is not a particularly special case.

If the header declares things like global static variables, you of course can't define them more than once. Typically a library will include definitions for the data it declares (or, better, not declare any static global data) so your code that uses the library shouldn't duplicate those.

Comment: If the shared header declares constant variables like "const int A=100;", are there conflicts?

Comment: How about global non-static variable definition like "int A;"?

Comment: @unknown: Having that in the header file would be a problem. That's a definition, not a declaration. It should be "extern int A;", and then just a single definition (int A;) in the library implementation. This is how e.g. the "errno" interface is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything will happen unless some objects have been instantiated in the header file:

i.e.:

```
CMyStringType superMansName("Clark Kent");
```

Will result in a link error where the object exists in both the static library and your code.